# How to change WindowStart WindowEnd in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a problem with the Azure Data Factory Pipeline Timezone. I want to create a regularly copy job on schedule that the Daten will transported every 15min from SQL Server to Azure Datawarehouse.

The whole copy process is running but there's problem on the WindowStart. The schedule(Pipeline) used UTC time but we are in Germany(UTC+1), so the WindowStart will  always 1 hour late than our local time.

For exsample our local time is 16:00 and I need to update the data from 15:45 to 16:00. But the schedule will set a `windowstart=14:45` and a `windowend=15:00`.

Is there anyone have any idea?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two properties which allow to shift schedule (see [Dataset Availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-create-datasets#dataset-availability)):

> **anchorDateTime**:   Defines the absolute position in time used by the scheduler to compute dataset slice boundaries.
>
> **offset**:   Timespan by which the start and end of all dataset slices are shifted.

You can play around with these two. I think they are supported in both `dataset/properties/availability` and `pipeline/properties/activities/scheduler` configuration sections.

Looks line negative offset is supported, so you can try this:

```
"availability": {
    "frequency": "Minute",
    "interval": 15,
    "offset": "-01:00:00"
}
```